# Config file changes when moving from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, configuration, package

Our project has been moved from windows server to linux server. In windows "config.php" file, the packages installed is defined as:

```
define('HTML2TEXT_PATH', "c:\\catsbin\\html2text.exe");
```

How to give the path when moved to linux server?
I have the same package installed in linux with the command

```
sudo apt-get install html2text
```

and it is located at /usr/share/doc/html2text/changelog.Debian.gz.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `html2text` is probably located in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`. Also see [How to list files installed by an apt-get package?](https://superuser.com/q/720660/173513)

Comment: how to specify the location in config.php file? Which file is to be specified?

Comment: Shall I give like this? define('HTML2TEXT_PATH', "\usr\share\doc\html2text\changelog.Debian.gz");

Comment: @KayalVizhi, no since you cannot run "changelog.Debian.gz".  You need an executable.  Do this: `sudo find / -name html2text -print`, it will show you where the executable file is.  Use that.

Comment: I got results as follows /usr/bin/html2text
/usr/share/doc/html2text
/usr/lib/mime/packages/html2text. Which one to use?